# Getting error "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')" in Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play

I am trying to run an **android project using Eclipse**, unfortunately, I am getting an error as "No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version')".

For fixing this I did the following

1. try to copy "/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib library project" but as per my understanding in the latest version of android the "google-play-services_lib" is brokedown into multiple libraries which is under "/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms".
2. I copied "/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms" in to my eclipse workspace.
3. Restart the eclipse and try to add "please select a library project" from **project selection** but it was hidden.

   please find the attachment for the errors
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]
   [image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to resolve this error.

1. Go to the file at **google-play-services_lib/res/values/version.xml** and view the raw integer for that symbol:

   < integer name="google_play_services_version">4030599 < /integer >

Replace this into **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<meta-data
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
   android:value="4030599"/>
```

2. Goto

**Eclipse -> import -> existing android code -> browse -> navigate to google-play-services_lib FOLDER (android-sdk/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject).**

Then in your project control click ->

**properties -> android -> libraries, add -> select the project you just imported -> ok**

I hope it will work for you.